# Failed to build VPN on Amazon EC2 service

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2

I've followed this tutorial to build a VPN on EC2:

[PPTP VPN on Amazon EC2](http://yzhang.net/blog/2013-03-07-pptp-vpn-ec2.html)

But when I run these steps, I always fail to connect to EC2 through VPN. Every time, the system confirms a connection, but eventually the system stops and reports a failure.

In the log: `/var/log/messages`, I can see:

```
pppd 2.4.5 started by ec2-user, uid 0
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
Modem hangup
```

I am confused on these items:

- What kind of IP should I input to `/etc/pptpd.conf`? My IP domain is 192.168.0.xxx. I input 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2-100 to `/etc/pptpd.conf`. Will this be a check point?
- How to check if I have enabled port 1723 on EC2?

Can anybody give me some ideas on how to debug this case?

Comment: another question is: what is the server name? should i take EC2 public DNS as vpn hostname?

Comment: Is there a firewall and/or proxy on client or server side?

Comment: I use win10 and i have installed macfee to defend virus. But I'm sure it is ok because i can access other VPN servers.

Comment: What about [Amazon EC2 Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)?

Comment: i have set security group to enable all traffics from any port, but still fail

Answer (score 2):

PPTP uses two different protocols, TCP port 1723 is used for initial setup, but the data streams use GRE -- [Generic Route Encapsulation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation) -- which is neither TCP nor UDP -- it's IP protocol number 47.

You need to create a security group rule to allow GRE traffic.  This requires that your instance be in a VPC, since EC2 Classic security groups do not support a rule like this.

TCP 1723 seems to be open, or you wouldn't be seeing the log entries.

Comment: @skyworld Note also that [macOS Sierra no longer support PPTP](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/06/25/pptp-vpns-no-longer-supported-by-apples-built-in-vpn-client-on-macos-sierra-and-ios-10/) because of [numerous security vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security), you should maybe consider using something more recent such as OpenVPN.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni that is, unfortunately, a very good point.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not sure if this command is what you are discussing: "iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT", i have tried this command but still failed for login

Comment: Hi Ortomala, thanks for your reminder. What i need now is just to build a VPN so that I can access google to search some documents. PPTP should be enough for me.

Comment: @skyworld no.  I'm referring to the EC2 security group that controls external access to your instance.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hi MIchael, I have set this security group to "all traffic, all protocol, all port range, source to 0.0.0.0/0". I believe i have enabled all, right? thanks.

Comment: I checked /etc/log/messages, I found this: "CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)". Is this you mentioned?

Comment: If you are allowing "all traffic, all protocol" in the security group, that should include GRE.  The next question -- I suspect -- is where you are connecting **from**.  The router or firewall device on the client side may not be allowing GRE.  Packet sniffing on the EC2 instance may be of help.

Comment: @MIchael when I setup connection through my win10 notebook, i think i have selected pptp protocol. But i didn't find any tab which i could select GRE. At the EC2 side, i don't know how to setup a sniffer to detect. What i know is to check /var/log/messages for clues. Can you give me some tips on how to sniff on EC2 for these? Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway i can use to check pptp's log?